# How to determine which of a project's package references are not needed?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a solution with projects, which builds OK.
The projects are mostly old-style (XML format) `*.csproj`, not the newer SDK-style, and the projects reference NuGet packages.

I believe some packages references aren't needed or are obsolete i.e.:

- The package reference is defined, in the `*.csproj` and/or `packages.config`
- But the package reference isn't needed, i.e. the package isn't used by the project's source code, and the project would still build if the package were removed

The problem arises when converting to SDK-style project format -- because the `packages.config` (created by the VS IDE) contains a project's dependencies **and sub-dependencies** but a new SDK-style project only needs to defines its dependencies (not its sub-dependencies).

**How can I find which package references aren't needed?**

Please assume that:

- I can parse the `*.csproj` and/or `packages.config` and so I know the list of all package references -- what I don't know is which references are needed
- I'm only interested in packages on which a project depends directly, i.e. I don't want packages which are needed at run-time but not at build-time, because they're a dependency of a dependency.

---

I don't want to have to experiment -- i.e. "Remove each package reference in turn, and try to rebuild the project, to see whether the reference is needed at build time" -- too time-consuming.

The only algorithm I can think of is:

1. Open the referenced package using reflection and get the list of types or namespaces which is defines
2. See whether those are used in the project -- by searching for namespace strings in the source code

Can you suggest a better way -- a more accurate way, or maybe using an existing tool?

Comment: Once you've converted a project you can do a `dotnet restore` which generates `obj/project.assets.json` which contains a graph (in JSON) of all your dependencies. You can then use that to work out which are top level dependencies. It's not quite right though as you'll cut any references to packages which are both direct and transitive references, and you won't cut references to completely unused packages

Comment: Visual Studio 16.10 have "Remove unused references" feature, see [changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#NETProductivity). It *should* be better than any handwritten solution

Comment: @JL0PD Thank you, I could upvote that if it were answer. So --I think that sub-dependencies (i.e. the dependencies of a dependency) must be explicitly referenced if it's an old-style non-SDK project format (e.g. with a packages.config), and need not be referenced if it's an SDK-style *.csproj -- isn't that so? Do you happen to know which of these scenarios the "Remove unused references" feature supports, or is it both i.e. it correctly varies depending on the format of the *.csproj?

Comment: Oddly the [rationale for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/remove-unused-references?view=vs-2019), i.e. that it reduces application startup time, appears to contradict the observation [in my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68140022/49942) which says that unused references aren't in the meta-data.

Comment: @ChrisW, I think that it's gonna work only for SDK-style projects, not old ones. Currently no one should use old format except for cases when you need to use COM (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with Visual Studio 2019 16.10 there's [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#NETProductivity) called "Remove unused references" that removes references to other projects & nuget packages from project file. Currently it's in preview and you need to enable it: go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `C#` > `Advanced` and select `Show “remove Unused References” command in Solution Explorer (experimental)`.

After that you will be able to remove references from project
[image]

I'm sure they gonna move it somewhere else in feature because it's not only for C#, but for dotnet in general

Comment: Hmm - alas it does not appear for me.  Perhaps stand on one leg and put a fork in my eye.  It is a Xamarin project after all.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if a package is referenced but not used, then it *doesn't* appear in the built assembly's manifest.

So I think that check will work, assuming the assembly can be built (i.e. so that its manifest exists).

There may be an edge-case, where a referenced implementation is needed at run-time but isn't in the manifest -- if the implementation is dynamic-loaded; but dynamic loading is uncommon.